# What is the spring-boot-starter-actuator 1.3.0 compatibility version of spring-integration-jms

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

What is the spring-boot-starter-actuator 1.3.0 compatibility version of spring-integration-jms?

Comment: if you use Spring Initializer, it will automatically pull in the compatible dependency.

Answer (score 2):

4.2.1.

See the [dependency pom](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L137).

The current release (1.3.2) uses [4.2.4](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L137).

You should use maven or gradle to manage your dependencies.

Comment: The versions are also [listed in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions)

Answer (score 0):

**Exact Proven Solution to your Question**

1. If you use Spring-boot-starter-parent version 1.3.0.RELEASE, it will download the spring-integration-bom 4.2.1.RELEASE POM file.
2. If you refer the [Spring-Integration-Bom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-bom/4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-integration-bom-4.2.1.RELEASE.pom) file, you can see the spring-integration-jms.4.2.1.RELEASE. Hence your version should be spring-integration-jms.4.2.1.RELEASE.jar.

Comment: @Naresh, As stated by Andy, please always use Maven or Gradle to manage your dependencies.